# Accessing generic type's known properties

Tags: generics, rust, types

I've been recently trying to modify a function that takes as input vectors of different types. However, I know that all possible types that will ever appear in vectors have a certain property - a property I'd like to modify as part of this function. For example:

```
pub fn modify_generic_structs<L>(vec_of_types: &Vec<L>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    
    for custom_type in vec_of_types.iter_mut() {
        // modify property based on a pre-defined rule
        // we guarantee each custom_type has .property!
        custom_type.property = someRandomValue;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I feel like I'm missing an elegant way to accomplish this - in theory one could rewrite this function into as many functions as there are types and branch out when they are called, but seems like an overkill (or is it?). Thanks!

Comment: Just add a subtrait of L that provides mutable access property you care about. Also, `vec_of_types` will need to be `&mut Vec<L>` (or `&mut [L]`). You'll need a real method, not just a property, to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would make a method in your trait that returns `&mut property`:

```rs
trait HasProperty {
    fn property_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Property;
}
```

Then you can implement it for structs that have it:

```rs
struct A {
    property: Property,
}

impl HasProperty for A {
    fn property_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Property {
        &mut self.property
    }
}
```

And call that function instead of accessing the member:

```rs
*custom_type.property_mut() = some_random_value;
```

I've called this `property_mut` because by convention, getters in rust will have two versions, one for shared references and one for mut references, with no suffix and `_mut` suffix respectively. For example, `Vec` has [`first`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.first) and [`first_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.first_mut).

Comment: As a side note, if all you need to support is assignment, then having the trait provide `fn set_property(self, value: PropertyType);` instead is more flexible. You can `impl SetProperty for &mut A` for example, but you could also `impl SetProperty for &Cell<Property>`.